# PySpark Configurations wtihin Jupyter Notebook

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

Im currently trying to configure a Spark Context inside Jupyter Notebooks using a python kernel and pyspark, but none of the changes I am making are being implemented.

For example, I change the number of cores per executor and see the change take effect within the Spark UI Environment Tab but not in the executors tab

(I don't have 10 reputation yet so I can't embed the actual images)

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEBTB.jpg) 
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQMFO.jpg)

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
import pyspark
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
sc = SparkContext("local", 'CompanyData')

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('CompanyData')
.config( "spark.sql.broadcastTimeout","36000")
.config("spark.memory.fraction",".8")
.config('spark.rpc.io.serverThreads','64')
.config('spark.executor.memory','4g')
.config('spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled', 'true')
.config('spark.executor.cores','4')
.config('spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors',"1")
.config("spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors", "5").getOrCreate()
```

I'm using a jupyter notebook to do all this and I'm not quite sure in what area of the progression the misalignment is happening

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying the code to

```
sc = SparkContext("local[*]", 'CompanyData')
```